# How to transfer "frozen" NFT on another wallet using Phantom?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, metaplex, nft, phantom

I can't send NFTs that have `state - frozen`. I get an error that the account is frozen or a signature error.

How do I do it? I read that I should try to send them through `Metaplex` somehow. But I have no idea how to do it in my JavaScript code to `unfreeze the token account` first and then `add it to a transaction` to transfer it to another wallet.

Answer (score 3):

Correct, frozen NFTs can not be transferred. They have to be thawed first.

The freeze authority can do that.

In cases of programmable NFTs (pNFT) this has to be done by the `Metaplex Token Metadata Program`. This will be done automatically when using the metaplex token metadata transfer function.

```
import { transferV1 } from '@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata'

await transferV1(umi, {
  mint,
  authority: currentOwner,
  tokenOwner: currentOwner.publicKey,
  destinationOwner: newOwner.publicKey,
  tokenStandard: TokenStandard.ProgrammableNonFungible,
}).sendAndConfirm(umi)`s
```

https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/transfer

Comment: Oh, thanks. But I only have PublicKey freeze authority. It's ok? Or I need secretkey for sign? You show some example but idk how to use this in my JS code (project). I first get the token owner accounts and transfer them via createTransferInstruction, then sign using my wallet. So how do I do it here? If it's sending through some umi here, I don't know what it is. Is it possible to get some more detailed example from you? And how to define umi? Thanks

Comment: You can find more on how to use umi here https://developers.metaplex.com/umi/getting-started
no need to get token owner accounts, work with createTransferInstruction, sign with your wallet manually.
This transfer command basically does everything for you.